# Resource files are not not publishing in ipfs name publish

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ipfs

I made sample dapp application for interacting with smart contract and i developed a basic ui when i am publishing it to ipfs like i did seeing a tutorial and ipfs documentation, i can get only index.html file and supporting scripts and css files are throwing error file not found. can any pls help me out in this issue.

Comment: Hi there. What did you see in the tutorial, and exactly what commands have you tried? What is the error being output?

Comment: i used ipfs add -r <my-directory> command and took my directory hash and published on the browser url. I am getting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 for all my files in chrome console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you're linking to the resources the wrong way. Make sure you're referring to your resources with **relative** URLs, so instead of doing `<script src="/my-script.js"></script>` (absolute link) you do `<script src="./my-script.js"></script>` (relative link).

This is because a IPFS website could be loaded in many contexts. Linking to `./my-script.js` would work correctly at all times while absolute would work in some but not all.

Some examples:

Development context, you load `http://localhost:3000`, `/my-script.js` (absolute) works alright because your website root is `localhost:3000`.

Gateway context, you load `http://ipfs.io/ipfs/$yourHash`, now `/my-script.js` would not work, as then it tries to load from `http://ipfs.io/my-script.js` instead of `http://ipfs.io/ipfs/$yourHash/my-script.js`. Relative link fixes that.

Dnslink context, you load `http://example.com`, again `/my-script.js` would work correctly, because your website root is `example.com`.

So verify your resource links are actually relative. If they already are, please post your code so we can look into it further.